# Duplicating a window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to duplicate a window in tkinter ?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x100")

def new_window():
    # Code to duplicate the window
    pass

button = Button(root , text = "Sample button")
button.pack(pady = 20)

mainmenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = mainmenu)

file_menu = Menu(mainmenu , tearoff = False)
menu_1 = Menu(mainmenu , tearoff = False)
menu_2 = Menu(mainmenu , tearoff = False)
menu_3 = Menu(mainmenu , tearoff = False)
menu_4 = Menu(mainmenu , tearoff = False)

mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "File" , menu = file_menu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "Menu 1" , menu = menu_1)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "Menu 2" , menu = menu_2)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "Menu 3" , menu = menu_3)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "Menu 4" , menu = menu_4)

file_menu.add_command(label = "Duplicate window" , command = new_window)
menu_1.add_command(label = "Sub-menu 1")
menu_2.add_command(label = "Sub-menu 2")
menu_3.add_command(label = "Sub-menu 3")
menu_4.add_command(label = "Sub-menu 4")

mainloop()
```

What I want is to create a new window and all the elements that are in the first window should be there in the new window as well.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter without using classes ?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Here's some documentation on [`Toplevel`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html),

Comment: if you put code in `function` or `class` then you can use it many times and you can easily create many windows with the same content. And this is how we create widgets - we put code in class and then we can use widget many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class to present the UI, then you can create many similar UI using the class:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        parent.geometry("500x100")

        button = Button(parent, text="Sample button")
        button.pack(pady=20)

        mainmenu = Menu(parent)
        parent.config(menu=mainmenu)

        file_menu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=False)
        menu_1 = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=False)
        menu_2 = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=False)
        menu_3 = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=False)
        menu_4 = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=False)

        mainmenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Menu 1", menu=menu_1)
        mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Menu 2", menu=menu_2)
        mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Menu 3", menu=menu_3)
        mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Menu 4", menu=menu_4)

        file_menu.add_command(label="Duplicate window", command=self.new_window)
        menu_1.add_command(label="Sub-menu 1")
        menu_2.add_command(label="Sub-menu 2")
        menu_3.add_command(label="Sub-menu 3")
        menu_4.add_command(label="Sub-menu 4")

    def new_window(self):
        win = Toplevel()
        MyUI(win)

root = Tk()
MyUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, while useful, this is creating identical windows, which isn't _quite_ the same thing as duplicating an existing one. (I don't think there's a practical way to actually do that.)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without classes ? I am asking this because there is too much of code in my other program where I didn't use classes , so I won't be able to change everything into a class.

Comment: @Lenovo360 You can use function instead of class.  But I prefer class over function.

Comment: @acw 1668 , I mean I won't be able to change everything into a class because there is a lot of code in my other program , so I am searching for an option in which I don't need to convert anything into a class(or use a class).

Comment: I don't think there is such an option.

Comment: This is the way better answer to your question @Lenovo360