# Tkinter independent windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a gui that I wrote with tkinter and I want to call it again with a button how do I do this (They will be independent of each other)

I want to do like this:

```
import tkinter

root = Tk()
root.title("test")

def testt()
   root()

Button(root, text='window +', command=testt).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicating a window in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65640872/duplicating-a-window-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

You also have to import some modules as shown.
Try this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Toplevel

def testt():
    root1 = Toplevel()
    root1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `TopLevel` in `test(`) function.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("test")

def testt():
   root1 = tk.Toplevel()
   

tk.Button(root, text='window +', command=testt).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot output:

[image]